# How to cast an object Run-time using Reflection in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, reflection, casting

i am developing a windows application and in that i created a class for common look and feel setting 
 CommonAppearance class Code :

```
static void SetCommonAppearance(Label ctrl){ //some appearance setting code}
static void SetCommonAppearance(GridGroupingControl ctrl){ //some appearance setting code}
static void SetCommonAppearance(GradientPanel ctrl){ //some appearance setting code}
static void SetCommonAppearance(Form ctrl){ //some appearance setting code}
static void SetCommonAppearance(ComboBox ctrl){ //some appearance setting code}
static void SetCommonAppearance(CheckBox ctrl){ //some appearance setting code}
static void SetCommonAppearance(RadioButton ctrl){ //some appearance setting code}
static void SetCommonAppearance(Button ctrl){ //some appearance setting code}

public static void UseCommonTheme(Form form)
{
    List<Control> lstControls = GetAllControls(form.Controls);
    foreach (Control ctr in lstControls)
    {
       string temp2 = ctr.GetType().Name;
       switch (temp2)
       {
          case "TextBox":
               SetCommonAppearance((TextBox)ctr);
               break;
          case "AutoLabel":
               SetCommonAppearance((Label)ctr);
               break;
          case "GridGroupingControl":
               SetCommonAppearance((GridGroupingControl)ctr);
               break;
          case "ButtonAdv":
               ApplyCustomTheme((ButtonAdv)ctr);
               break;
          case "CheckBoxAdv":
               SetCommonAppearance((CheckBox)ctr);
               break;
          case "ComboBoxAdv":
               SetCommonAppearance((ComboBox)ctr);
               break;
          case "RadioButtonAdv":
               SetCommonAppearance((RadioButton)ctr);
               break;
       }

    }
}
```

this is acceptable when there are less control application to set common appearance but in my application there are number of different type of controls are used. 
 In the method `UseCommonTheme(Form form)` instead of using switch case Can we use **reflection** to cast the controls ? somthing like

```
foreach (Control ctr in lstControls)
{
    string controlType = ctr.GetType().Name;
    SetCommonAppearance((class reference of 'controlType')ctr);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using .net 4 you can take advantage of the dlr (dynamic language runtime):

```
foreach (dynamic ctr in lstControls)
{
    SetCommonAppearance(ctr);
}
```

The dlr will resolve the correct overload for you.

If you want to use reflection:

```
var type = typeof(CommonAppearance);
var methods = type.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public);
foreach (Control ctr in lstControls)
{
   var setAppearanceMethod = 
        methods.FirstOrDefault(m => m.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType == ctr.GetType());
   if(setAppearanceMethod!=null)
       setAppearanceMethod.Invoke(null, new[] { ctr });
}
```

Comment: @Bhushan I added an implementation that uses reflection

Comment: @Algerto what is "item" in `setAppearanceMethod.Invoke(null, new[] { item });` ?

Comment: @Bhushan os sorry its a mistake, should be `ctr`